# Visual Studio Format getter and setter on one line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, format, getter-setter, code-readability

I just scaffolded a project using Template Studio WinUI v5.3 and when I press Ctrl K D to format document, the getter and setter is placed on new lines.

**current.cs**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProp
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

I want:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

The readability is bad for a class with many properties. I searched a lot through Visual Studio and I still can't find the solution. The cause I suppose its related to a new C# version. My other projects use the same Visual Studio settings, but this formatting does not apply to them.
Do you know where can I find the setting for this problem?

**Problem**
I write a prop like this `public int MyProperty { get; set; }`, then after I press Ctrl K D  it moves them on multiline format.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options#csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [this in your .editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options#csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks):

```
[*.cs]
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
```

Or you can set it directly in VS: `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Wrapping` and check "Leave block on single line".

[image: Image of the above setting]